# Nhibernate query after change collection

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

`User` have many `Role`s:

```
public class User
{
    private ISet<Role> _roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    public virtual ISet<Role> Roles { get { return _roles; } }
}
```

I add role to user (`user1.Roles.Add(role1)`).

Why first of these two queries does not return `user1` as second?

```
session.QueryOver<User>()
    .JoinQueryOver<Role>(u => u.Roles)
    .Where(x => x.Id == role1.Id)
    .List();    

session.QueryOver<User>().List()
    .Where(u => u.Roles.Contains(role1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of this *magical* behaviour is hidden in `Session` pattern and its `.Flush()` operation.

The ISession (see [Chapter 2. Architecture](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture)):

> #### ISession (NHibernate.ISession)
>
> A single-threaded, short-lived object representing a conversation between the application and the persistent store. Wraps an ADO.NET connection. Factory for ITransaction. **Holds a mandatory (first-level) cache of persistent objects, used when navigating the object graph or looking up objects by identifier.**

The interesting here is the `first-level` cache ... by `identifier`. What happened is that the `User` was updated inside of the `ISession`. Only in this session, because it was not synchronized with DB... it was not flushed

The [9.6. Flush](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing) is *(in a nutshell)* a way how NHibernate

> From time to time the ISession will execute the SQL statements **needed to synchronize** the ADO.NET connection's state with **the state of objects held in memory**. This process, flush, occurs by default at the following points... (see more in the link)

So, what we know now is: Session is keeping updated record of a User. DB does not, because session.Flush() was not called. We run the second query which looks like this:

```
session.QueryOver<User>()
// forces to load all rows from DB
// these rows are converted into User instances by their ID
// and while our updated User in memory already is... it will be used
// instead of persisted one
.List()
// now we do in memory searching
// i.e. check the User instances, which of them does have role1
// and even our newly updated (just in memory) user is found
.Where(u => u.Roles.Contains(role1));
```

The second query, does really filtering on a DB side... but the synchronization was not done... no `.Flush()` ... User is not found.

So, please, do read the soruces mentioned above to get more detailed understanding about: session, first-level cache and flushing

Do call:

```
session.Flush() // after adding Role1 to User
```

immediately when adding Role to User... and both queries will return the same results

Comment: So there is no way to query over unsaved cached entities? I do not want flush every single change immediately to simplу canceling them.

Comment: Well, in fact, It does not make sense! Either we do **write** operation or we do **read**. We never should do combination inside of one transaction. So, I would strongly suggest: split write operations (inside one transaction) and later start new operation (its own transaction) to read the data... PS: I am not saying that write operation cannot read... it can read any supporting data. But it may not read what it is just to about to persist....

Comment: Can we do thing like: open window, load some entities to edit (and query over that unsaved entities here), save all changes through one transaction.commit()?

Comment: I am just trying to explain what happened (your question) and suggest the usual approach. So, if you want to do it differently... not a problem ;) Anyhow: I would not recommend to query collection which items were just changed. Really. I'd rather 1) call operation enclosed in transaction: Load what needed, update that call session.Flush() 2) call different operation, enlcosed in different transaction (even for read) ... be sure that reading will target updated DB. Anything in between will bring you only issues... Does this help? Because I am suggesting different then your last comment...

Comment: Ok, I can flush everything immediately, but what to do if user Cancel - save entity copy before changing and commit that copy back to DB when needed? Or another solution - don't flush, but cache all used entities inside window viewmodel and make queries over them. Which better?

Comment: The Cancel decision should be available only before the write operation will start. Once user will confirm changes... all should be done at once. Because we will be working with transaction, if anything will appear during that process, we should/have to rollback. Summary: read and cache ... until some point. All in small chuncks,not in a long lasting session nor transaction. Gether all the data needed for write operation and ask user if proceed. If yes then do all at once... After commit, reload all the cached data. That would be the way I will go...